ReactHlsPlayer - How to avoid auto load of a video on refresh the page?
In react app, I am using react-hls-player.
 <ReactHlsPlayer
         className="video-player"
         src={link} // Here link is with .m3u8
         controls
         playsInline
         poster={thumbnailImage}
         onContextMenu={handleContextMenu}
 />

When I am refresh/loads the page video starts loading(backend calls will go). Here, I want to avoid it, I want to start load the video when user clicks on it means while playing.
Is there any callback function where we can modify this player? Or any other way? Please help me.

I think the simplest way is to just set src to an empty string until user clicks on the video element.
Can be something like this:
  const [hlsSrc, setHlsSrc] = useState<string>("");
  const onUserClicked = useCallback(() => {
    setHlsSrc(src)
  }, [src]);
  // use hlsSrc as src in ReactHlsPlayer


Empty String will not support by this plugin. Already tried.

I've tried that on react-hls-player==3.0.7 (latest version of https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hls-player), worked fine. Which version you're using?

I am using the latest one "^3.0.7"

What do you mean by "not supported" then? When I pass an empty string as a src it doesn't load any chunks which is what you want

Its keep on showing loader symbol when src is blank

Loader is not part of react-hls-player lib, it must be in your code. You can hide it as well, when user haven't clicked on video yet. {hlsSrc != '' && loading && <YourSpinner/>}

I didn't add any loader. Its from player itself.
